Why is the boot manager file for MS DOS 5.00 missing?
I downloaded the MS-DOS 5.00 boot ISO file from the Internet Archive and tried to boot it using YUMI (Your USB Multiboot Installer). However, it failed to boot, displaying a message that the boot manager file was missing, which suggests something went wrong. After rebooting into Windows and examining the installation medium, the absence of the boot manager file was confirmed. Despite thorough online searches, I have been unable to find this file. If you have any solutions, please reply to this inquiry.

Can you give more details? What sort of computer are you trying to boot with this? Which file is missing? Is Secure Boot enabled? Please add this information to the question itself, not as a comment down here.

Perhaps https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ could offer help. Why 5.0? 6.2 was last release, and much improved. Also: old 16-bit hardware, or VM?

Can you provide a link to the ISO file you downloaded?

DOS 5 is not a UEFI operating system. It never was. It does not include a UEFI boot manager file: it never did.
I'm not familiar with YUMI. If it is able to boot non-UEFI systems, it will have instructions for doing so.
